# How to Compare Method ReturnType to Predefined Types

Tags: .net, roslyn

Using Microsoft Roslyn I am trying to determine if a methods return type is void.
I have the handle on my MethodDeclarationSyntax and can see the property Called "ReturnType" this is a PredefinedType of void.  Do I have to actually check the keyword kind?  Is there a better way to do this?

```
((PredefinedTypeSyntax)methodDec.ReturnType).Keyword.Kind() != SyntaxKind.VoidKeyword
```

Is there a recommended method of accomplishing what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For `void`, that's perfect, since there's no other way to say it. Saying `System.Void` is explicitly prohibited there.

For other predefined types like `int`, keep in mind that you can write it either with the keyword or with the .NET type `System.Int32`. Depending on your scenario, you might actually care to distinguish between them, and so the syntactic check would still be correct. If you don't care about the difference and just want to know if it's an integer, you should then do some binding with a `SemanticModel`:

```
var methodSymbol = (MethodSymbol)semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(methodDecl);
if (methodSymbol.ReturnType.SpecialType == SpecialType.System_Int32)
{
    /* ...whatever goes here */
}
```

`MethodSymbol` also has a `ReturnsVoid` property which you might find useful if you happen to have the symbol for it.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe will throw an exception for non pre-defined return types.

Try this instead:

```cs
public static bool IsVoidFunction(this MethodDeclarationSyntax ms) 
  => ms.ReturnType is PredefinedTypeSyntax predefined 
     && predefined.Keyword.IsKind(SyntaxKind.VoidKeyword);
```